# Can't able to execute any script after dfs.block.size is changed in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

To test a scenario I have executed below in Hive and now any of my normal queries are not running and it returning same error even for all different query executions.

Command I executed at initial is

```
set dfs.block.size=1073741824;
select * from l_rate where CONVERSION_START_DATE='20160701'
```

Later I have executed below

```
set dfs.block.size=${hiveconf:test}
select * from ${hiveconf:test} limit 10
```

However I stop my above testing and came to my normal tasks. Now I can't able to run even normal queries

```
select * from country limit 10;
```

Now I getting below error for all executions on different tables

> FAILED: RuntimeException java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "${hiveconf:test} select * from ${hiveconf:test} limit 10

Please help me to get rid from this error ! even I logout my session in Quoble and reconnected but doesn't help.

Comment: If you are executing the select command from "Hive Query Editor" in Hue, make sure to select only the command you want to run and click on "Execute" button.

Comment: Hi Manoj, I am using Quoble to execute my hive queries. However I am doing in new query window and it throwing back above specified same error

Comment: Execute your set command again: set dfs.block.size=1073741824;

Comment: @facha Shall I know how should executing again should fix the issue...

Comment: The error message is explicit: **you just forgot to add the command delimiter** ; **at the end of your SET command**, so Hive concatenated the SELECT inside the SET value.